# BaseURL in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, routes

I have an application in Symfony 2. It is deployed on IIS server.

The problem is, I need to get it work on multiple URLs:

- www.somedomain.com/myapp/app.php - for production
- www.somedomain.com/myappdev/app.php - for testing
- myapp.localhost/app.php - for development

How can I do that? I need to correctly generate URL for resources(js, css files). Also after deployment, generated URL are missing the /myapp/ (/myappdev/) segment.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix your routes with /myappdev by adding it to your app/config/routing.yml file under the prefix key.

If you use relative URLs for the resources then you won't have a problem with the domain it's on and it will work anywhere you put it.